# Unit testing with XUnit, ADO.NET, SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, xunit

This question is about using XUnit with ADO.NET for a To Do List app using Nancy. I'm hoping for some insight on why an `Assert.Equal` test is failing, even though the outputs appear to be identical.

I have a Task class with two properties: `id` and `description`.

The database for this app has a corresponding `tasks` table. User input is used for the description, and the `id` is an auto-incrementing identity column.

The `Task` class has a static List property `All()`. Each task is added to `All()`, and you can retrieve the list of all tasks by calling `Task.All()`.

Here's the `Task` class:

```
namespace ToDoList
{
  public class Task
  {
    private int id;
    private string description;

    public Task(string Description, int Id = 0)
    {
      id = Id;
      description = Description;
    }

    public int GetId()
    {
      return id;
    }


    public string GetDescription()
    {
      return description;
    }

    public void SetDescription(string newDescription)
    {
      description = newDescription;
    }

    public static List<Task> All()
    {
      List<Task> AllTasks = new List<Task>{};

      SqlConnection conn = DB.Connection();
      SqlDataReader rdr = null;
      conn.Open();

      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tasks", conn);
      rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

      while(rdr.Read())
      {
        int taskId = rdr.GetInt32(0);
        string taskDescription = rdr.GetString(1);
        Task newTask = new Task(taskDescription, taskId);
        AllTasks.Add(newTask);
      }

      conn.Close();

      return AllTasks;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
      SqlConnection conn = DB.Connection();
      SqlDataReader rdr;
      conn.Open();

      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tasks (description) OUTPUT INSERTED.id VALUES (@TaskDescription)", conn);

      SqlParameter testParameter = new SqlParameter();
      testParameter.ParameterName = "@TaskDescription";
      testParameter.Value = this.GetDescription();

      cmd.Parameters.Add(testParameter);

      rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

      while(rdr.Read())
      {
        this.id = rdr.GetInt32(0);
      }
      conn.Close();
    }

    public static void DeleteAll()
    {
      SqlConnection conn = DB.Connection();
      conn.Open();
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tasks;", conn);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I define `DB.Connection` as the connection string in *Startup.cs*:

```
...
  public class DB
  {
    public static SqlConnection Connection()
    {
      SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=todo_test;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
      return conn;
    }
  }
...
```

Now here's the test I use to see if it works:

```
namespace ToDoList
{
  public class ToDoTest : IDisposable
  {
    [Fact]
    public void Test_All()
    {
      //Arrange
      var description = "Wash the dog";
      var description2 = "Water the plants";
      Task testTask = new Task(description);
      testTask.Save();
      Task testTask2 = new Task(description2);
      testTask2.Save();

      //Act
      List<Task> result = Task.All();
      List<Task> testList = new List<Task>{testTask, testTask2};

      //Assert
      Assert.Equal(result, testList);
    }

    public void Dispose()
      {
        Task.DeleteAll();
      }
    }
}
```

The output in the console only says that the test failed:

```
ToDoList.ToDoTest.Test_All [FAIL]
  Assert.Equal() Failure
  Expected: List<Task> [Task { }, Task { }]
  Actual:   List<Task> [Task { }, Task { }]
```

I did some console logs, and the `id`s and `description`s for the tasks in each list are identical.

In addition, when I test with:

```
  List<Task> result = new List<Task>{testTask, testTask2};
  List<Task> testList = new List<Task>{testTask, testTask2};
```

The test passes.

I'm not really sure how to approach this to see why the test is failing. Any ideas would be great!

Comment: It is meaningless to compare tasks as how could we tell they are equal to each other? You should design more accurate test cases instead. Meanwhile, it is usual to use mock services in unit testing, while leave the testing with SQL Server in later phases (such as integration and UAT).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by your first sentence? I want to test that tasks are saving to the database and returning correctly. I'm not sure why `result` and `testList` are not returning as equal, when `All()` returns all the tasks in the database as a list. I will look into mock services for unit testing, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to overwrite the `Task.Equals()` method for that `Assert.Equal()` to succeed, otherwise the default reference equals semantics will be applied.